# Prepared Statement - как указать предусловия?

Tags: odbc, java, sql

Суть: 
    пишу парсер xml, который потом зависывает результаты в таблицу. При истинности некоторый значение (например: `clientID == 0`) - запись производить не надо. Не могу придумать как бы это сделать.

Comment: Банальный if, цепочки предикатов.

Comment: то есть примерно так, 
if (ps.clientID == 0) ps.clear();
else ps.executebatch; //?

Comment: У вас проблема в парсинге xml или в ветвлении?

Comment: Там проблема несколько в другом. xml парсится и укладывается в котентейнеры (некое представление таблицы(индекс элемента и адрес блока в xml)), далее, к каждому контейнеру добавляются 5 полей, общих для каждой таблицы, потом этот контейнер передается в PS. За раз происходит по несколько записей, в разные таблицы. У меня в голове, по крайней мере, мне нужно перед экзекьютом поставить проверку на необходимое значение, если буду ставить там, где это сейчас происходит, придется плодить ещё кучу проверок. А так, для трех контейнеров из 15, в случае если один столбец равен нулю.

Answer (score 1):

Например как-то так:

```
if (product != null && location != null && courseType != null && category != null) {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM Courses WHERE "
                + "product = ? "
                + "and location = ? "
                + "and courseType = ? "
                + "and category = ?");

        pstmt.setString(1, product);
        pstmt.setString(2, location);
        pstmt.setString(3, courseType);
        pstmt.setString(4, category);
    } else if (product == null && location != null && courseType != null && category != null) {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * FROM Courses WHERE "
                + "location = ? "
                + "and courseType = ? "
                + "and category = ?");

        pstmt.setString(1, location);
        pstmt.setString(2, courseType);
        pstmt.setString(3, category);
    }
```